# How can I shorten a path in red hat linux?

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, filepath

So I have a bunch of files that I use for testing in a directory with a long path so say there are 10 files located at `/home/grammin/testFiles/program1/important/.`  What I would like to do is have something in my bashrc? maybe that is like `fileDir = /home/grammin/testFiles/program1/important/` and then whenever I would like to access a specific file on the command line all i have to do is type something like `ls fileDir/FILE1`.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achive this by `ln` command. something similar to this

```
ln -s /home/grammin/testFiles/program1/important/ fileDir
```

Running this one will be enough I think

Comment: same answer, you arrived first!

Comment: Is there anyway I can make this systemwide though, so any directory I'm in I can just type fileDir/FILE1?

Comment: @Grammin This will create a symbolic link to the folder in the current folder you are running. Therefore, I don't think we can make this systemwide. Maybe Dennis' and Basile Starynkevitch's answers are more correct for this question.

Comment: I tried both options I think this is the best solutions, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just set a variable: `fileDir=/home/grammin/testFiles/program1/important`.

Now `ls $fileDir/FILE1` will have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a symlink to the path you want, and use the link path as a "typing shortcut" when using terminal.

For example, if you have `/this/is/a/very/long/filesystem/path`, you could create the link with `ln -s /this/is/a/very/long/filesystem/path pth` and then use `ls pth/FILE1`

Answer (score 0):

in your .bashrc file, add
    importantdir=/home/grammin/testFiles/program1/important/

Then use that variable with a dollar, e.g.
    ls $importantdir/FILE1